# Get next level from a given level factor

Tags: r

I am currently making my first steps using R with RStudio and right now I am struggling with the following problem:
I got some test data about a marathon with four columns, where the third column is a factor with 15 levels representing different age classes.
One age class `randomAgeClass` will be randomly selected at the beginning, and an object is created holding the data that matches this age class.

```
set.seed(12345678)
attach(marathon)
randomAgeClass <- sample(levels(marathon[,3]), 1)
filteredMara <- subset(marathon, AgeClass == randomAgeClass)
```

My goal is to store a second object that holds the data matching the **next higher** level, meaning that if age class 'kids' was randomly selected, I now want to access the data relating to 'teenagers', which is the next higher level. Looking something like this:

```
nextAgeClass <- .... randomAgeClass+1 .... ?
filteredMaraAgeClass <- subset(marathon, AgeClass == nextAgeClass)
```

Note that I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877324/how-do-i-increase-or-decrease-an-ordered-factors-level-make-a-factor-equal-to) StackOverflow question, which seems to partially match my situation, but the accepted answer is not understandable to me, thus I wasn't able to apply it to my needs.

Thanks a lot for any patient help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make sure thar the levels of your factor are ordered by age:

```
factor(marathon$AgeClass,levels=c("kids","teenagers",etc.))
```

Then you almost got there in your example:

```
next_pos<-which(levels(marathon$AgeClass)==randomAgeClass)+1 #here you get the desired position in the level vector
nextAgeClass <- levels(marathon$AgeClass) [next_pos]
filteredMaraAgeClass <- subset(marathon, AgeClass == nextAgeClass)
```

You might have a problem if the `randomAgeClass` is the last one, so make sure to avoid that problem

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I needed!